# Como le doy permisos a un usuario "x" para que pueda ver y administrar applications en wso2?

Tags: users-roles, wso2

Tengo el siguiente problema. he creado un application con el usuario admin por defecto del wso2 y cuando quiero acceder a ese application tanto para ver su informacion como para administralo con un usuario "x" solo puedo ver el applications que viene por defecto. Estoy administrando los usuarios y sus permisos desde el **wso2 identity server**, ya le he dado a mi usuario "x" el role de admin con todos los permisos y también le asigne el role que se crea al generar el application.

Comment: Are you referring to an application created in API Manager Store?

Comment: exactly, I created the application with the default user admin and now when I try to assign the application role from identity server to other user, they can't see the application created by the admin. thanks for answering

Comment: You should use application sharing feature for this. Please have a look at the following document. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Sharing+Applications

Comment: That's not how you should do it. See my answer below.